# Laravel 5 - Set Model and Table during Runtime Not Working

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing two different types of auth for 'student' and 'consultant', thus two tables.

So far everything works fine. A user can choose usertype and then login, but when I'm printing {{ Auth::user()['username'] }} in the page error occurs: only 'student' name can be displayed, since I specified model and table in config/auth.php to be 'Student' and 'students'. As for consultant users, they can successfully login, but username can't be displayed.

I tried to set model and table with config during runtime but doesn't work, here's part of my AuthController:

```
    if( $request->only('usertype')['usertype'] == 'student' ) {
        Config::set('auth.model','Student');
        Config::set('auth.table','students');
        $userprovider = new \Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider(app('hash'), 'App\Student');
        Auth::setProvider($userprovider);
        $this->redirectPath = '/student/home';
    }

    else if( $request->only('usertype')['usertype'] == 'consultant' ) {
        Config::set('auth.model','Consultant');
        Config::set('auth.table','consultants');
        $userprovider = new \Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider(app('hash'), 'App\Consultant');
        Auth::setProvider($userprovider);
        $this->redirectPath = '/consultant/home';
    }  $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);      

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }
```

Seems the Config::set doesn't work at all. What could be the problem?
I'm using Laravel 5.1.

Comment: You're modifying the user provider only for the single request that is done when user tries to log in. During subsequent attempts the original config will be used. You'd need to modify the config for every request based on what kind of user is authenticated.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible I change it globally? It's so hard to modify request in the blade.php pages, like {{ Auth::user() }}

Comment: You could do that in middleware - store user type in session on successful login and then in the middleware read that value from session and set config variables - https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware. Or implement your own user provider that will use different tables to load users depending on that value https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful!
Just adding another solution: using some multi-auth package, like Sarav\Multiauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try answering my question, based on jedrzej's solution in the comment.

Config::set did work, but only for once and needs to be modified for every request for authentication. In this case, doing a middleware is an ideal solution - store user type in session on successful login and then in the middleware read that value from session and set config variables - laravel.com/docs/master/middleware.

Another easier solution is using some package for multi-auth. I used Sarav\Multiauth (https://packagist.org/packages/sarav/laravel-multiauth) and it works perfectly.